# Use Redis.Message from outside of the pubSub callback

Tags: haskell, redis, publish-subscribe, scotty

In the [documentation for Hedis](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-0.14.4/docs/Database-Redis.html#g:24), an example of using the `pubSub` function is given:

```hs
pubSub :: PubSub -> (Message -> IO PubSub) -> Redis ()

pubSub (subscribe ["chat"]) $ \msg -> do
    putStrLn $ "Message from " ++ show (msgChannel msg)
    return $ unsubscribe ["chat"]
```

Given that `pubSub` returns a `Redis ()`, is it nevertheless possible to re-use this `msg` message further down in the code, from outside the callback?

I'm calling `pubSub` from a Scotty endpoint which runs in the `ScottyM` monad, and should return (to keep a long story short) a `json msg`

```hs
myEndpoint :: ScottyM ()
myEndpoint =
    post "/hello/world" $ do
        data :: MyData <- jsonData
        runRedis redisConn $ do
            pubSub (subscribe ["channel"]) $ \msg -> do
                doSomethingWith msg
                return $ unsubscribe ["channel"]

        -- how is it possible to retrieve `msg` from here?
        json $ somethingBuiltFromMsg
```

Alternatively, is there a way to use Scotty's `json` from within the callback? I haven't been able to do this so far.

Comment: Should the line with `json` be indented further to the right such that it is in the do block of the post endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you meant to indent the line with `json` further.

You can use mutable variables in `IO` for that, e.g. `IORef`:

```hs
import Data.IORef (newIORef, writeIORef, readIORef)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

myEndpoint :: ScottyM ()
myEndpoint =
    post "/hello/world" $ do
        data :: MyData <- jsonData
        msgRef <- liftIO (newIORef Nothing)
        runRedis redisConn $ do
            pubSub (subscribe ["channel"]) $ \msg -> do
                writeIORef msgRef (Just msg)
                return $ unsubscribe ["channel"]
        Just msg <- liftIO (readIORef msgRef)
        json $ doSomethingWithMsg msg
```

Edit: I guess I don't really know if the runRedis function blocks until the message has been received, if that is not the case then you can use an `MVar` instead:

```hs
import Control.Concurrent.MVar (putMVar, takeMVar, newEmptyMVar)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

myEndpoint :: ScottyM ()
myEndpoint =
    post "/hello/world" $ do
        data :: MyData <- jsonData
        msgVar <- liftIO newEmptyMVar
        runRedis redisConn $ do
            pubSub (subscribe ["channel"]) $ \msg -> do
                putMVar msgVar msg
                return $ unsubscribe ["channel"]
        msg <- liftIO (takeMVar msgVar)
        json $ doSomethingWithMsg msg
```

Comment: Good point for the indent,  I fixed the question

Comment: Very interesting answer, thanks. Is it the only way though?

Comment: fwiw, `runRedis` does block until the message has been received

Comment: I think using a mutable variable in IO like this is the only way. Ideally, the library would have included an alternate version of the pubSub function that can return a value, but that is not the case as far as I can tell.

Comment: so there's no alternative like using transformer stacks (or anything) to call `json msg` from within the callback?

Comment: well actually I don't see how that could work... nevermind, I'll go with mutable variables. thanks a lot.